# Parse Queries and express results

Tags: javascript, express, parse-platform

I'm developing a web application using Parse for my backend. I have encountered a problem with this function:

```
app.get("/users/:username", function (req, res) {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  var name = req.params.username.substring(1);
  query.equalTo("username", "" + name);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      res.render(results.email);
    },
    error: function() {
      res.send("failed");
    }
  });
});
```

I want to take the field email from the JSON file of this type:

```
[
    {
        "createdAt":"2016-01-18T20:35:01.015Z",
        "date":{"__type":"Date","iso":"1995-08-14T00:00:00.000Z"},
        "email":"tester@test.com",
        "lastname":"Test",
        "name":"Tester",
        "updatedAt":"2016-01-18T20:35:01.015Z",
        "username":"tester",
        "objectId":"AoEAt6rUJF"
    }
]
```

But my code doesn't work and I can't use the results. How can i fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `results` object returned from the [Parse.Query](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html) query is an array of [Parse.Object](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#props) objects. This array does not have an `email` property which is why nothing was rendered. What you want to do is obtain the email of the first item in the `results` object:

```
query.find({
  success: function (results) {
    // Use 'get' to obtain the value of an attribute.
    res.send(results[0].get('email'));
  },
  error: function () {
    res.send("failed");
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks! your code works if i used res.send instead of res.render ...thanks!

Comment: Can you select this as the correct answer so as to help the next person that has this issue?